# How do I stop toggle button loop based on button value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a toggle menu with a button that changes value. I'm trying to stop the toggle loop so that when the value = "thank you" & you click on the button it doesn't toggle.

1. Button #1 value = Contact
2. After clicking "Contact" that button value changes to "Send message" and a second button (button #2) appears ("submit") in the toggle drop down
3. After clicking ("submit") button #2 the value of button #1 changes to "thank you"

https://jsfiddle.net/9882acxn/

CSS:

```
#container {height: 200px; width: 200px; position: relative; background: red;}
```

jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {  
$("#container").hide();

$("#button").on('click', function() {
if($("#container").is(":visible"))
return false;

$("#container").toggle();
this.value = this.value == 'send message' ? 'contact' : 'send message';
});

 $("#button2").on('click', function() {
    $("#container").toggle();
    $("#button").val('thank you');


if($("#button").val('thank you'))
return false;
 });


}); 
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="button" value="contact" />
<br />
<div id="container">
<input type="button" id="button2" value="send" /></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

If your are done after sending the message, just unbind the click event .

```
$("#button").unbind('click');
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/9882acxn/1/

**Approach 2**

You can add the following condition in the `$("#button").click`

```
if($("#button").val() == 'thank you')
            return false;
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/9882acxn/3/

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

```
$("#button").replaceWith('<span>Thank You</span>');
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/9882acxn/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Change `if($("#button").val('thank you'))` (which sets the value *to* "Thank You") to `if($("#button").val().equals('thank you'))`

.equals() because strings are immutable in most languages (I forget if `==` works in js).

Also reorder the statements:

```
$("#button2").on('click', function() {
    if($("#button").val('thank you'))
        return false;
    $("#container").toggle();
    $("#button").val('thank you');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work. When "thank you" is clicked it still toggles?

Comment: You need to reorder your statements.  Check for the value *before* calling .toggle(), see the edit I made.

Comment: @Draco18s  '==' does work in javascript, it only checks the value comparision. === does value and type comparision

20 == '20'; // true
20 === '20'; // false

Comment: Thanks @zeroCool, I've been working in C# so much I'm used to the more explicit call (which will still work in js).